# Can I create a Google Compute Instance from an Instance Template in another project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Title says it all:

Can I create a Google Compute Engine instance in one project, based off of an Instance Template living in another project?

Comment: My bad - just the term _template_ made me think to images: those two are interchangeable in some contexts. I'll update if I find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: This question is fine and produced a usable answer. Properly tagged for context. I would personally ignore calls for you to be more formal than this. I spend my days inside Goog cloud and more text would add nothing to the question, IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn’t a direct way to create a Google Compute Engine Instance in one project, based off of an Instance Template living in another project.

Instance templates define the machine type, boot disk image or container image, labels, and other properties based on the project where the template was created, for example the service-account or the network.

Having said that, I tried to reproduce the scenario in my own projects and I have found a way to create a new instance in a project (project-2) using an Instance Template “extracted” from a different project (project-1):

I created an Instance template in the project-1 following the  next [steps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates)

1. Go to the [Instance templates](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instanceTemplates) page in my project-1.
2. Click on the instance template that you want to copy.
3. Click **Create similar**.
4. Go to the **command line** link at the end of the page and copy in an editor the parameters provided.
5. I’ve edited some parameters like the project, network, service-account, so on.
6. Open a Cloud Shell on  project-2 and paste the parameters already edited.
7. As a result I have a new Instance Template with the same parameters (machine type, boot disk image or container image, labels, etc.) in the project-2 .
8. With this new template I was able to create a new Instance in project-2.

On the other hand, I recommend you to review the following guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to provide a better context on what you are doing and what do you want to achieve.